# How to run `grunt connect` process on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs

I want to know if is possible to run a *grunt-contrib-connect* command in order to serve your static files with Heroku.

My Grunt file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
          base: 'www',
          keepalive: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect']);    
};
```

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: grunt
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "herokoloco",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "bower install"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13", 
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
        "bower": "~1.3.9"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x"
    }
}
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
> node_modules
v www
    index.html
bower.json
Gruntfile.js
package.json
Procfile
```

It works perfectly locally using Heroku's "foreman start web", but does not work on Heroku. I just get this error in my logs:

> 2014-10-08T21:19:23.620448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
>   host=shielded-waters-3266.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=4d669be2-a362-4968-8349-b83b8ad0e2f6 fwd="198.245.95.126"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Answer (score 1):

It worked once I actually set some dynos. To do so, I issued the following command from the terminal inside of my Heroku project:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: This means you can't grunt for free. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size

Answer (score 0):

You can have Heroku run any command you want after completing install by setting the command to start your server in your Procfile. So, something like:

```
web: ./node_modules/grunt/.bin/grunt my-grunt-command ; node app.js
```

should work.

Comment: Totally understand you, but i tried and didn't work. What i don't want is to use a nodejs server, i want to run `grunt connect` on the `web` task within the `Procfile`, but it simply didn't worked.

Comment: To make this work, you'll likely need to get the PORT environment variable and figure out how to add that as an option to grunt-contrib-connect.

Comment: I've did that, on the `grunt-contrib-connect` options i've put `port: process.env.PORT || 3000`, and in the Heroku log says the Heroku assigned port, but still didn't work.

Comment: kevinwolf, I believe grunt options are JSON, not executable Javascript, so that won't work. Why don't you post your grunt config for more feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the grunt dependencies listed in your package configuration (including `grunt-cli`), make sure you remove the `hostname` part of the connect configuration and use the processes port.. ie "port: process.env.PORT || 5000" in you connect configruation. That works for me.